# Return string value * is expanded upon return of call

Tags: linux, bash, awk, sh, ash

I am building a script running in `#/bin/sh` on a modem running a variant of openwrt:

```
root@Inteno:~# ls -l /bin/sh
lrwxrwxrwx    1 root     root             7 Oct 15  2014 /bin/sh -> busybox
```

The script is gathering and presenting data. I have run into a problem. I need to return a string of a computername connected, this in the fifth column:

```
root@Inteno:~# cat /tmp/dhcp.leases
1449374455 00:00:00:00:00:00 192.168.1.245 * 00:00:00:00:00:00
1449371955 11:11:11:11:11 192.168.1.135 android-27718d96d947c125 11:11:11:11:11
```

This is how it is supposed to work:

```
root@Inteno:~# printf '%s\n' $(grep -i 11:11:11:11:11 /tmp/dhcp.leases | awk {'printf $4'})
android-27718d96d947c125
```

However, if the connected computer does not have a network name set, it is listed as a `*`:

```
root@Inteno:~# printf '%s\n' $(grep -i 00:00:00:00:00:00 /tmp/dhcp.leases | awk {'printf $4'})
script2.sh
test.sh
```

Upon execution, the `*` is returned and expanded as the filenames in the running folder which leads to the script failing. This is rewritten from a nested function where the input file is a list of mac addresses, one per line:

```
while read enhet; do 
  printf '%-6s%-32s%-5s%-19s%-4s%-16s%-20s%-4s%-3s\n' "Navn: " $(cat /tmp/dhcp.leases | grep -i $enhet | awk {'printf $4'}) "MAC: " $(cat /tmp/dhcp.leases | grep -i $enhet | awk {'printf $2'}) "IP: " $(cat /tmp/dhcp.leases | grep -i $enhet | awk {'printf $3'}) "Signalstyrke(RSSI):" $(wlctl rssi $enhet) "dBm"; 
done < temp_assoc
```

What I need is to return a `*` character as a string, without expanding it.

Can it be done in this context?
Best regards

Comment: Thanks for the heads up. I think it is much more readable now.

Comment: I'm too lazy right now, but I guess using "$(<big piped stuff>)" instead of plain $(<big piped stuff>) could do the job. Maybe you have to fiddle out where to put the additional double-quotes.

Comment: Essentially, it's the difference between echo * and echo "*"

Answer (score 3):

The result of a command substitution is subject to pathname expansion. You need to quote it to prevent characters like `*` being treated as wildcards.

```
printf '%s\n' "$(grep -i 00:00:00:00:00:00 /tmp/dhcp.leases | awk {'printf $4'})"
```

Also, your `grep | awk` is a bit of an antipattern:

```
awk '/00:00:00:00:00:00/ {print $4}' /tmp/dhcp.leases
```